# Unable to send nodemailer error response from node.js to angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nodemailer

Here I'm sending a mail when the form is submitted. Everything is working fine, the only issue is even though the mail is not sent because of wrong authentication or internet problem  ,the user is getting the success message. I want that the user should get an error message if the mail is failed to get sent.

> client

```
    this.mail= function() {
    var data = ({
        name :this.name,
        email :this.email

    })

    //Post Request
      $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/contact2', data
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $mdToast.show(

                  $mdToast.simple()
                    .textContent('Thanks for your message '+data.name)
                    .position($scope.getToastPosition())
                    .hideDelay(5000)
                );
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    $mdToast.show(
             $mdToast.simple()
               .textContent('Something went wrong, Please TRY AGAIN '+data.name)
               .position($scope.getToastPosition())
               .hideDelay(5000)
           );
  });

    });
```

> server

```
function send(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);

  var data= req.body
  smtpTransport.sendMail({ 
     from: "<email@gmail.com>", 
     to: data.email, 
     subject: "Website Submission from "+data.name,
     text: 'You have a new submission with the following details...,
  }, function(error, response){  //callback
     if(error){
         console.log(error);
     }if{
         console.log(" Message sent "+data.name);
     }

     smtpTransport.close(); 
  });
  res.json(data);
}
```

Comment: Syntax error in callback, you are using `if{` please see my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server : You can create and send error message from server as

```
if(error){ 
     res.json({ 
      Status : false,
      message : error
     })
}else{ 
     res.json({ Status : true,
     message : 'Success'
     })
}
```

Client : Here  you can capture it by

```
function successCallback(response) {
if(response.Status){ 
     console.log(response.message);
}// for success
else{ 
     console.log(response.message) 
} //for error
```

}

Comment: In the client side I'm unable to console.log response.message and response.Status....It shows me undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can set and send additional `data.emailSent = true` or  `data.emailSent = false` as:

```
if(error){
       data.emailSent = false;
} else{
       data.emailSent = true;
}
```

On client you can check this flag and show success or failure accordingly.

Comment: thanks for ur help, i was thinking of doing something like this if(error){res.json({message: 'error'})}.
 how to fetch this variable  on client side

Comment: Its same thing what I have suggested- do it this way or that way. You can access this variable on client as `response.message`, please mark answer correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Zeeshan Hassan and pooja for helping me out, at first I was unable to access the status and message . I just made these few changes to Pooja's solution and its working

```
function successCallback(response) {
       console.log(response.data.Status);
       if (response.data.Status){console.log(response.data.message);}
`     `else{ console.log(response.data.message) }
```

Comment: This doesn't work with me. It only opens an empty page with  {"Status" : true, "message" : "Success"}.